# Which Office 365 licenses offers unlimited storage

Tags: sharepoint-online, licensing, storage

I'm currently on Microsoft Business Standard(currently my storage is almost full) and looking to upgrade - to a license model where i can get unlimited storage.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no type of license offers unlimited storage.

You can purchase an unlimited amount of additional SharePoint storage.

Reference:

[Add storage space for your subscription](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/commerce/add-storage-space?view=o365-worldwide)

Comment: Thanks. Really!? I was with a call with Micrisift sakes and she mentioned if i upgrade to Enterprise e.g E1 i would have unlimited.This is misinformation from MS. What options exactly do i have with additional storafe e.g whats the max i can get?